# How to resolve a promise when all files are fetched?

Tags: javascript

Here is a functon that requests images files. How to return a promise when all files are loaded?

```
function request() {
      for (const [src, nodes] of this.icons.entries()) {
      fetch(`${this.baseHref}assets/images/${src}`)
        .then((res) => res.text())
        .then((content: string) => {
          nodes.forEach((node: LayerNode) => {
            const { icon } = node;
            const { color } = icon;
            const replaceIcon = getReplaceIcon(this.defPointIcon, color);
            const defIcon = getDefIcon(content, color);
            this.cachedIcons.set(node, { defIcon, replaceIcon });
          });
        });
    }}
```

I have tried this:

```
const promises = [];
  for (const [src, nodes] of this.icons.entries()) {
      promises.push(fetch(`${this.baseHref}assets/images/${src}`));
    }
```

Then

```
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((res) => res.text())
  .then((content: string) => {
    nodes.forEach((node: LayerNode) => {
      const { icon } = node;
      const { color } = icon;
      const replaceIcon = getReplaceIcon(this.defPointIcon, color);
      const defIcon = getDefIcon(content, color);
      this.cachedIcons.set(node, { defIcon, replaceIcon });
    });
  });
```

Problem is I lost the `nodes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is that you lost the reference to `nodes`, you can make your promise to include it in the result through a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```
const promises = [];
for (const [src, nodes] of this.icons.entries()) {
  promises.push(fetch(`${this.baseHref}assets/images/${src}`).then(result => [result, nodes]));
}
```

Then you should change the way you read the result:

```
  .then(([res, nodes]) => res.text().then(content => [content, nodes]))
  .then(([content, nodes]: [string, any[]]) => {
```

Comment: TypeError: res.text is not a function

Comment: I didn't try it because the snippet in your question isn't reproducible, btw what's the type of `res` in that row? You can see it through a debugger

Comment: `res` is `Response` type

Comment: I use this: `fetch(`${this.baseHref}assets/images/${src}`).then(
          (result: Response) => [result.text(), nodes]
        )`. Then `this.loadIcons()
      .then(([res, nodes]) => [res, nodes])
      .then(([content, nodes]: [string, any[]]) => {
         console.log(content);
      });` I got  `(2) [Promise, Array(9)]`

Comment: You're right, let me fix the answer

Comment: Thank you a lot, I am awaiting an edit version, that is strange for me